# How to ignore "Cannot read property 'username' of undefined" on a web page

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, ejs

This is the home page or ('/') on localhost:3000. I wanted this home page to work in a way so that when a user logs in they will have their username displayed. Currently, this only works when the user logs in. However, I want to ignore the error if they are not logged in so that anyone could access the page without being logged in. I am using passport to authenticate users across a session if that help and you can view my home route and the snippet of where I'm executing the ejs in home.ejs file.

```
//Home page route in js

app.get('/',(req, res) => {
  res.render('home.ejs', {name: req.user.username})
})


//.ejs file snipped
       <li>
         <%if(locals.name){%>
         welcome <%=name %>
         <form class="" action="/Users/logout?_method=DELETE" method="post">
           <button type="submit" name="button">Logout</button>
         </form>
         <%}%>
       </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work :)

```
app.get('/',(req, res) => {
  res.render('home.ejs', {
    name: req.user !== undefined ? req.user.username : ""
  })
})
```

Comment: Hi Tymur, just tried it out and everything works! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the optional chaining operator along with the nullish coalescing operator.

```
app.get('/',(req, res) => {
  res.render('home.ejs', {name: req?.user?.username ?? ''})
})
```

Comment: Note that support is good, but some people on mobile platforms might be stuck with a browser that still doesn't support the _optional chaining_ or _nullish coalescing_ operators. That doesn't matter if you're doing this on the nodejs side of things. +1 — I would use it anyway.

Comment: @hev1 you should check his nodejs version before use it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59574047/how-to-use-optional-chaining-in-node-js-12

Comment: Thank you very much for the response! I took a look at the link that Ahmed provided and found that I am runnin node 12.18.0. Once I update it I will give it a try. Once again thank you!

Comment: @ElijahHernandez No problem.