# Why is optional chaining not working in my Node REPL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax, optional-chaining

I literally copy pasted example code from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) but optional chaining wont work in my node(v12.13.0) REPL. Throws out a syntax error saying that the dot after the question mark is invalid. What's going on ? I have already used this expression in a React App and it seems to be working fine.

```
const adventurer = {
  name: 'Alice',
  cat: {
    name: 'Dinah'
  }
};


const dogName = adventurer.dog?.name;
console.log(dogName);
// expected output: undefined

console.log(adventurer.someNonExistentMethod?.());
// expected output: undefined
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's only coming for Node 14 under --harmony:
[How to use optional chaining in Node.js 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59574047/how-to-use-optional-chaining-in-node-js-12)

You can use babel optional chaining plugin if you want this feature in node:
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-syntax-optional-chaining.html

Comment: Thanks I was wondering why the expression was working in my react-native app but not my node REPL. Must be a babel plugin which comes by default.

Comment: Yes the default preset which babel uses in react-native apps created using the cli tool enables optional chaining.

Comment: I'm still getting a syntax error even with that package installed.