# How to use optional chaining in vite?

Tags: vite, optional-chaining

I found the question [How to use optional chaining in Node.js 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59574047/how-to-use-optional-chaining-in-node-js-12).

And there's a problem, it doesn't work in my vite@2.4.4 project. It actually works fine on iphone12, but doesn't  work in my another android mobile.

Then I used `edge://inspect` debugging to find this:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
 // const serverResponseCode = response.data?.code;
```

[image]

How should I configure my Vite?