# Please fix the error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined."

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to code a discord bot for a friend's server. It's supposed to be a fun bot so I thought it would be funny to add a spam command. But I keep getting Errors when I do. Can someone help me out with the error? The code and the error are both given below.

It works fine when I do the command `-spam @[user]`. But the moment someone mistypes it and does maybe `-spam [random characters]`, it shows me the error

CODE:

```js
client.on("message", msg => {
  if(msg.content.startsWith(prefix+'spam ')){
    let mentions = msg.mentions.members.first().id;
    if(!mentions) return msg.reply("I'm sorry! That user does not exist.")
    for(var i=1;i<=5;i++) {
      msg.channel.send('<@'+mentions+'>')
    }
  }
})
```

And the error is

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/runner/VADER-Bot/index.js:44:44)
    at Client.emit (events.js:326:22)
    at Client.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/home/runner/VADER-Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/home/runner/VADER-Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/runner/VADER-Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/runner/VADER-Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/runner/VADER-Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/runner/VADER-Bot/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
repl process died unexpectedly: exit status 1
```

Comment: And what's the actual problem? There's only one instance of a property named `id` in your script. Hence... `msg.mentions.members.first()` returns `undefined`. Check the documentation when that happens and adjust your script accordingly.

Comment: You have even mentioned the problem yourself already. `-spam @[user]` vs. `-spam [random characters]` + `msg.mentions`

Comment: @Andreas Hi. Thanks for your reply, but I'm new to coding as a whole. So can you please speak to me as if I'm a kid? Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (`?.`). It will return undefined or null if the value before is [nullish](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Nullish). If it isn’t, it goes to the next property (`id` in this case)

```js
let mentions = msg.mentions.members.first()?.id //notice the '?.'
if(!mentions) return msg.reply("I'm sorry! That user does not exist.")
```

This will not throw an error if no one is mentioned, and will go to the "I'm sorry..." message.

**Edit:** due to your comment, it seems that you are using an old version of node.js. This is a bit longer but should do the trick.

```js
const check = msg.mentions.members.first()
if(check) let mentions = check.id
```

Comment: This is the fastest way to fix it as you need to add a single character (`?`)

Comment: Hi. I tried what you said. This also showed an error saying 

`Unexpected token '.'`

Comment: What version of node.js are you using? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59574160/15781079)

Comment: I edited my answer for older versions of node.js

Comment: Turns out I was using an older version. Thanks a lot for your help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct if it helped! (Use the checkmark under the upvote/downvote buttons)

Answer (score 0):

The function `msg.mentions.members.first()` is returning undefined, try to log each part of this big object to see where you are missing your variable.

Comment: I'm new to JS and Coding as a whole so can you please talk to me like I'm a 12 year old? :D

Answer (score 0):

call the function first() on `let mentions = msg.mentions.members.first().id;`  separately and then assign id into mentions. Firstly make sure each object in `msg.mentions.members` there are definitions.

`const object1 = {  a: 'cat', b: 123, c: true  }`. If you want to access b's value you would type `const bValue =  object1.b`. So in that same way, `const object1 = {  a: { b: 'Dog' } }`, to access a's value, `const aValue = object1.a.b` would be the answer. So in your case you have to check if there is a object called mentions in msg and members in mentions and a function in object members which is highly unlinkely. First check `let members = msg.mentions.members` exist. if not you would again get TypeError: Cannot read property 'members' of undefined. Hope this is clear enough.

Comment: I'm new to JS and Coding as a whole so can you please talk to me like I'm a 12 year old? :D

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: `const object1 = {  a: 'cat', b: 123, c: true  }`. If you want to access b's value you would type `const bValue =  object1.b`. So in that same way, `const object1 = {  a: { b: 'Dog' } }`,

Answer (score 0):

`msg.mentions.members.first()` is undefined, which is expected because they typed -spam [something that doesn't contain a user]

Try checking if `msg.mentions.members.first()` exists, and if so get the id.  If not, then don't because you'll get an error.

```
client.on("message", msg => {
  if(msg.content.startsWith(prefix+'spam ')){
    let mentions = msg.mentions.members.first();
    if(!mentions) return msg.reply("I'm sorry! That user does not exist.")
    for(var i=1;i<=5;i++) {
      msg.channel.send('<@'+mentions.id+'>')
    //etc
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm new to JS and Coding as a whole so can you please talk to me like I'm a 12 year old? :D

Comment: Which part do you not understand?  It would be very difficult (and, asking a bit much) to talk you through this if you know nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Other people have said this. but you said you were new to coding so I will try to elaborate.
What you have is this:

```
let mentions = msg.mentions.members.first().id;
if(!mentions) return msg.reply("I'm sorry! That user does not exist.")
```

It's giving you this error because you are checking to see if the user exists AFTER you are getting the ID of the user, you should check to see if they exist FIRST. It can't set mentions to the ID because msg.mentions.members.first() is returning undefined.

```
let mentions = msg.mentions.members.first(); // set mentions variable to the member object
if(!mentions) return msg.reply("I'm sorry! That user does not exist."); // check if user exists
mentions = mentions.id; // set mentions to the id of the mentioned user
```