# can't use optional chaining (?)

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I try to use optional chaining in my nodeJS project.

I use version 15.8 (or any >12, I'm using nvm).

my project is run with flag esm

```
$ run.env -p ../../.env nodemon -r esm --watch ../../.env --watch ./src/ ./src/index.js
[nodemon] 2.0.12
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): ../../.env src/**/*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node -r esm ./src/index.js`
/home/dre/Projects/my/packages/backend/src/routes/account/login.js:72
    let user = await Account.findOne({ email: payload?.email });
                                                      ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

My eslint is not yelling at this syntax anymore, but no way to have it understood for node.

Any idea would help me a lot!

Comment: What node version are you running?  It's [not supported below version 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59574047/how-to-use-optional-chaining-in-node-js-12)...

Comment: It should work fine in 15.8 though, are you sure that's the version nodemon uses? Try logging `process.version`.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any older version of node on your system? And are you sure nodemon is using the correct version from nvm?

Comment: @AlexanderNied, @CherryDt, @derpirscher my version is 15.8
when I log the `process.versions` I got

`{
  node: '15.8.0',
  v8: '8.6.395.17-node.23',
  uv: '1.40.0',
  zlib: '1.2.11',
  brotli: '1.0.9',
  ares: '1.17.1',
  modules: '88',
  nghttp2: '1.42.0',
  napi: '7',
  llhttp: '2.1.3',
  openssl: '1.1.1i',
  cldr: '38.1',
  icu: '68.2',
  tz: '2020d',
  unicode: '13.0'
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enable this feature as it is not widely supported by applying the `--harmony` flag which applies the new ECMAScript 6 features.

According to [node.green](https://node.green/#ES2020-features-optional-chaining-operator-----), optional chaining will be supported starting with Node 14, but will still require the --harmony flag.

Comment: I tried to run it with the flag, but having the same error
`run.env -p ../../.env nodemon -r esm --harmony --watch ../../.env --watch ./src/ ./src/index.js`

I also tried to use node instead of nodemon but no better result

Comment: @dredtrake I cant reproduce the issue. Can you create a new dir and run `npm init` in there then try using optional chaining with and without the harmony tag?

Comment: I think it was due to the architecture of my project, I have set it again and had no problems anymore :)

Answer (score 0):

Updated to `v16.10` removed the esm flag put `"type": "module"` in my package.json

I now need to adapt my app a bit to make it work and fix some new errors.